# Using `eval` when building XD plugins

Tags: javascript, plugins, eval, adobe-xd

Is it possible to use `eval` or similar functions for executing code inside the XD plugin file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [Adobe XD Platform](https://forums.adobexdplatform.com/t/can-i-use-eval-or-similar-functions/40)...

> No. `eval` and similar methods of executing code are disabled. This is for a variety of reasons, including security-related concerns.
>
> This doesn’t, however, prevent you from running arbitrary code – it just means you have to get inventive. Before considering this path, however, be sure to consider whether or not you *really* need to run arbitrary code, as there may be considerable risks to doing so.

Some options:

- Use a JavaScript-in-JavaScript interpreter. Some possible options:

  - https://www.npmjs.com/package/sandboxr
  - https://www.npmjs.com/package/sval
  - https://github.com/NeilFraser/JS-Interpreter
  - https://www.npmjs.com/package/@axetroy/vm
- Use a mathematical expression evaluator. Some possible options:

  - https://www.npmjs.com/package/math-expression-evaluator
- Build your own scripting language!

  - This assumes you like building parsers, lexers, etc., but for those who like doing so, the option is available!

**Credits:** [Kerri Shotts](https://forums.adobexdplatform.com/u/kerrishotts) from Adobe.

Comment: Wow! Thanks @KerriShotts... `:)` I did add credits to you... Didn't know you are also here... `:)`